# How can i make a file with constants in django3.0.2 python3.6 and access it in all applications . Any github repository is also useful

Tags: python, django, python-3.6, django-3.0, python-django-storages

```
include(
    # the project different envs settings
    optional('envs/devel/*.py'),
    optional('envs/production/*.py'),
    optional('envs/staging/*.py'),

    # for any local settings
    optional('local_settings.py'),
    optional('path.py'),
)
```

What should be the folder structure I follow to build Django web application, I did not found any repo on github in which contains files that are made according to the environments. As i am moving from php to python i did not found how to exactly define the constants in python so that the value of the constants will not change anywhere.

```
print("currently i am using django-split-settings to include files")
```

Answer (score 0):

when using django you do not do this. rather in the settings.py file. you check whether the debug flag is true or false i.e. whether the project is in production or not. to change the settings for development/deployment.

## hosting on github

when you host it on github any thing is fine as long as you add a requirements.txt
to allow you to install the requirements on another machine. its a good rule of thumb to not use virtualenvs on different machines so it is rare to see them on github repos.

Comment: after doing a lot of research i found [link]https://django-project-skeleton.readthedocs.io/en/latest/structure.html

Comment: yeah thats is the structure. just put this in  your repo